# Magento checkout register new user in one step

Tags: magento, registration, shopping-cart, checkout

I have a problem in magento checkout. When I checkout while user is logout, it asks for login or register new user, now when new user register, it first take its billing information after pressing cotinue button it then goes to shipping information and then next step to shipping method and then payment. Can I have all these in one form ? like if its new registration, user fill billing, shipping, payment etc info all at once.

See images for more details.

[image: Step-1]

[image: Step-2]

[image: Step-3]

Comment: Any one did it before, or have any idea, any tutorial or anything ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By default in Magento there is no such ability to have this information on the one form, you need custom extension for this. Try to search for one step checkout module.
By the way - user is being created in Magento only after completing all of 6 steps of default checkout process.

Comment: Well, One step checkout have lot more options which are not needed. Any other workaround to have this done ?

Comment: Write the code your self if you can. To create custom addons for magento is not so difficult at all